# How isPresented of view.sheet becomes false?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I study cs193p, and there's question considering Lesson 12. here's the code snippet

```
    func body(for palette: Palette) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Text(palette.name)
            ScrollingEmojisView(emojis: palette.emojis)
                .font(.system(size: emojiFontSize))
        }
        .id(palette.id)
        .transition(rollTransition)
        .popover(item: $paletteToEdit) { palette in
            PaletteEditor(palette: $store.palettes[palette])
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $managing, onDismiss: {
            print("dismiss: \(managing)")
        }) {
            PaletteManager()
        } 
    }

    @State private var managing = false
```

The `managing` is controlled by a button to set it to true. After set `managing` to true, a sheet will be shown. And after click somewhere the sheet dismiss.
in console it prints `dismiss: false`

The question is i don't set the `managing`, so there must somewhere to set it to false. I guess this is in the sheet implementation code. but i cannot find it.

So the question is: where to set the `managing` to false, what's the mechanism.

Comment: "but i cannot find it" Well duh, SwiftUI's is closed source. You cannot find the source code of any of its implementation.

Comment: You can setup a binding to the state in the view that is being presented and set it to false to dismiss the view.